# Can we use apache Gremlin DSL for mutations (CREATE, UPDATE & DELETE)?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-java

Can we use apache Gremlin Domain Specific Language (DSL) for mutations (CREATE, UPDATE & DELETE)?

[Gremlin Java DSL](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-java-dsl)

```
@GremlinDsl(traversalSource = "com.sample.dsl.EmpTraversalSourceDsl")
public interface EmpTraversalDsl<S, E> extends GraphTraversal.Admin<S, E> {
    
    public default Vertex create(Employee employee) {
        return addV("employee");
    }

}
```

Every time, when I invoke this method, it creates double of what is there in the database.

Ex:

if there is, 2 employee then it become 4. 4 become 8 & so...

Comment: It sounds like your code is doing the equivalent of `g.V().addV()` and not `g.addV()`

Comment: Correct. `coalesce(__.V().hasId(id),
    __.addV("employee").property("O", "K"));` working fine. Any idea on how to do without `coalesce` in dsl?

Comment: If you're attempting to do a conditional write or upsert, you'll need to following this pattern:  https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#upsert

Comment: Want to use just `addV()`, without any condition. I guess, inside `DSL`, by default it starts with `g.V()`. that's why, it;s duplicating the insertion as mentioned by  
@KelvinLawrence

Comment: Are you able to share more of the code, especially where you use the DSL?

Comment: I am referring this github project https://github.com/datastax/graph-examples/blob/master/killrvideo/dsl/java/src/main/java/com/killrvideo/KillrVideoTraversalDsl.java Line number :  250 or 274

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I tried to create the vertex using the `EmpTraversalSourceDsl`, so the query ultimately looks like

```
g.V().hasLabel('employee').addV('employee').property(T.id, 'T12321321R'))
```

Resolved using `coalesce`